# How to insert parameters in a secure way in ActiveRecord minimum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, aggregate-functions

How can I do this, without risking an SQL injection attack?

```
nearest = Site.minimum('abs(latitude - ' + params[:lat] + ') - abs(longitude - ' + params[:lon] + ')', group: :id)
```

I've tried:

```
nearest = Site.minimum(['abs(latitude - ?) - abs(longitude - ?)', params[:lat], params[:lon]], group: :id)
```

But that doesn't seem to work. The documentation isn't very clear how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to [this Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) the second way you wrote *is* the safe way. What about it didn't work?

Comment: The second way doesn't function, because it expects column names when it sees an array. That syntax only works for when() and :conditions =>

Comment: When using sql functions, the rails builders start to break down.  You might want to look at Squeel which has better support for sql functions: https://github.com/ernie/squeel (or the railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails uses [`sanitize_sql_for_conditions`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_for_conditions) internally for dealing with placeholders. Of course, that method is protected so you can't (cleanly) use it outside of an ActiveRecord model. You can get around the protectedness using [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
nearest = Site.minimum(
  Site.send(:sanitize_sql_for_conditions, [
    'abs(latitude - ?) - abs(longitude - ?)',
    params[:lat].to_f, params[:lon].to_f
  ]
)
```

Or you could put that logic inside a `Site` class method so that you'd be allowed to use `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` without trickery:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.whatever_this_is(lat, lon)
    minimum(
      sanitize_sql([
        'abs(latitude - ?) - abs(longitude - ?)',
        lat, lon
      ])
    )
  end
end
```

and then in your controller:

```
nearest = Site.whatever_this_is(params[:lat].to_f, params[:lon].to_f)
```

Take note of the [`to_f`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_f) calls. If you don't include those then `params[:lat]` and `params[:lon]` will be Strings and `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` will quote them as such:

```
abs(latitude - '11.23') - abs(longitude - '42.6')
```

Your database may or may not be happy to see you trying to subtract a string from a number so it is best to say exactly what you mean and do the type conversion yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I've settled for this:  c = ActiveRecord::Base.connection; nearest = Site.select('ABS(latitude - ' + c.quote(params[:lat]) + ') - abs(longitude - ' + c.quote(params[:lon]) + ') AS distance, id').order(:distance).limit(1)

Answer (score 0):

Granted I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish from the example above, but it looks like you might be improperly using the minimum method which takes a method name as its first argument. For example:

```
Site.minimum(:latitude)
```

If you want to add conditions to it, I think you would want to use:

```
Site.where(country: 'USA').group(:id).minimum(:latitude)
```

Again, this example won't return the result you're expecting, but it should explain better how the API is used.